# Decimales tipo punto para el input type number de HTML5

Tags: jquery, html5, entrada

Tengo el siguiente input:

```
<input type="number" value="1.5" step="1" id="id_texto" />
```

Actualmente el valor del input me muestra 1,5. Pero lo que deseo, es que me muestre 1.5. Deseo que los decimales me lo muestre con punto, y no con coma.

Quizas con Jquery o alguna definición de lang=en. He buscado formas de resolverlo, pero no me ha resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es de internalizacion con el idioma mejor conocido como **i18n**, por defecto los navegadores seleccionan el idioma detectado (por medio internet y la localizacion)

**Tu solucion** es agregar una libreria, pero   hay muchas librerias y cambian con respecto al usuario version de Jquery entre otros, generalmente se debe agregar la libreria **`.js`**  y seleccionar el idioma de tu preferencia esto tambien influira en las fechas

un pequeño ejemplo usando el repositorio https://github.com/wikimedia/jquery.i18n puedes hacer esto:
en el header agregar la linea

```
<input type="script" src="jquery.i18n/src/jquery.i18n.language.js"</script>
```

y dentro de la pagina esta linea

```
$.i18n( {
    locale: 'en' // Ingles puedes elejir el idioma que necesittes
} );**
```

Comment: Pero si yo quisiera que solamente un determinado input number tuviera los puntos, y no afectar a otros que quisiera ocupar con comas, ¿como se podría hacer?

Comment: javascript y colocar el campo text y con pattern numero te explico en otra respuesta

Comment: seria algo asi <input type="text" pattern="[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+" required />

Comment: Ok, pero eso que pusiste: $.i18n( {
    locale: 'en' 
} );

Donde se debe colocar, dentro del document ready, o modifcar la libreria languaje???

Comment: Dentro en el document.ready

Comment: No me funciona, descarge el demo, y me sale varios errores:
jquery.i18n.language.js:692 Uncaught ReferenceError: pluralRuleParser is not defined
    at Object.getPluralForm (jquery.i18n.language.js:692)
    at Object.convertPlural (jquery.i18n.language.js:672)
    at Object.plural (jquery.i18n.emitter.js:134)
    at Object.emit (jquery.i18n.emitter.js:54)
    at jquery.i18n.emitter.js:48
    at Function.map (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Object.emit (jquery.i18n.emitter.js:47)

Comment: Debe se que me faltó agregar más librerias

Comment: Claro, falta una librería llamada pluralRuleParser, desde la pagina https://github.com/wikimedia/jquery.i18n no la tienen, pero la llaman..por eso está malo

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar JavaScript para editar el valor con

```
input.value = input.value.replace(',', '.')
```

Comment: Simplemente pone como valor el mismo valor pero sustituyendo la coma por un punto

Comment: no se puede, cuando el input está definido como number, lo cambia siempre a ','